# Parsing Kafka messages

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My question will be short and clean. I would like to parse json data which will be coming from the Kafka topic. Thus, My application will run as the Kafka consumer. I am only interested in some part in JSON data. Do I need to process this data using a library for example Apache-Flink? After that I will send the data to somewhere else.

Comment: You can use the [Kafka Streams API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-kafka-streams) to filter your specific json data. You can get more detailed information in the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/code-examples.html).

Comment: which type of Deserializer  are you using?

Comment: I use StringDeserializer now, but I will map String to a specific model.

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning you say "filter data", so, looks like you need a `RecordFilterStrategy` injected into the `AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory`. See documentation for this matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#filtering-messages

Then you say "interested in some part in JSON". Well, this doesn't sound like you need *records filtering*, but more sounds like *data projection*. For this reason you can use a `ProjectingMessageConverter` for slicing data by some `ProjectionFactory`. See their JavaDocs for more info.

Comment: you are right. I should not have said filter. Because I do not filter any of them. I accept all but just take some part in the message. I will try to use data projection, thank you.